# Python to get ids from shapefile don't return all records

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, pyqgis

I have some Python code to get the ids and georeference from a shapefile:

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
allLayers = canvas.layers()
nos = QgsFeature()
for i in allLayers:
    if i.name()=='path_nodes':
        path_nodes = i

nodedata  = path_nodes.dataProvider()

while nodedata.nextFeature(nos):
    i = i + 1
    print str(no.gid())
```

It does not return all of the ids. Can anyone help?

Comment: How many ids did it miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bananafish noted, `no` should be `nos`. You might also want to set `i=0` before the loop.

```
nos = QgsFeature()
while nodedata.nextFeature(nos):
    i = i + 1
    print str(nos.gid())
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `while` loop, `no` doesn't refer to anything, you need to assign it to the current feature. I don't know how the QGIS API works, so here's a somewhat ugly approach:

```
while True:
    try:
        no = nodedata.nextFeature(nos)
    except:
        break
    print str(no.gid())
```

Comment: @user1573901: no problem! Please consider accepting the answer (click the tick mark under the down arrow) if it solved your problem.